# AWS Glue create table at child level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

My folder structure in S3 bucket for parquet files is like below:

```
Parent
------- child
-------------- date partition 1
-------------------------------- parquet file 1
-------------------------------- parquet file 2

-------------- date partition 2
-------------------------------- parquet file 3
-------------------------------- parquet file 4
```

There is always only one "child" folder in "parent" directory. My S3 target path points to the "child" folder as the number of partitions may increase/decrease with time. However, Glue creates a table with the name as "Parent" and with 2 partitions - "child" folder and date partition. This is unexpected as "child" is not a partition, and S3 path already points to the child directory.

As of today, Glue crawler does not have option to specify regex-like paths for S3 targets. I have looked into classifiers of crawlers as well, but that seems like a way to describe the data in the parquet file and does not concern itself with paths. Is there a way to work-around this issue besides changing folder structure?

Comment: Can you post your crawler configuration here? What is the expected and actual table def from Glue console?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy the location is /path/to/parent/ (which is expected) and column names are also parsed as expected. However, the child folder is identified as a value in PartitionKeys list. This should not be the case.

Comment: Are your date partition folders named using the "=" convention? eg, date=20200101. If not, you may want to consider that. Does your S3 target path for your crawler end with a forward slash? If not, please ensure it does.